# Java case insensitive regular expression

Tags: java, regex, case

I just got this:

```
System.out.println("КОНТАКТЫ".matches("(?i).*контакт.*"));
```

and it always says "false".

I tried:

```
System.out.println("КОНТАКТЫ".matches("(?i:.*контакт.*)"));
```

and:

```
System.out.println("КОНТАКТЫ".matches("(?i:).*контакт.*"));
```

and:

```
System.out.println("КОНТАКТЫ".matches("(?i)^.*контакт.*$"));
```

and many others variations but I always have "false".

How to perform case insensitive search in java correctly so I have "true" in this regexp search?

What do I do wrong?

Comment: covert your *string* and *regex string*  in same case.

Comment: I really doubt if its a case insensitive check(I doubt if the case plays any role here). Both the Strings seem to contain special characters(UTF-8 characters, I guess).

Comment: Try method that sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ proposed: @System.out.println("КОНТАКТЫ".toLowerCase().matches("(?i).*контакт.*"));@

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to turn unicode case flag on:

`System.out.println("КОНТАКТЫ".matches("(?iu).*контакт.*"));`

More [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE)